# How to typecast boost::any to std::array<int, size> if I don't know the size?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have the following code:

```
boost::any x;
std::array<int ,3> arr = {1,2,3};

x = arr;
```

When I want to get back `std::array` values, I can do this:

```
auto arg = boost::any_cast<std::array<int, 3>>(x);
```

But if I don't know the size of `std::array`, how can I typecast from `boost::any` to `std::array`?

Answer (score 1):

If the size is dynamic, you can't use `std::array`.

If the type list is bounded, you can "just" check for each expected type. It may not be efficient.

Tricks using reverse visitation by typeid might alleviate the worst case behaviour. But I'd strongly consider using a properly dynamic container because that's clearly what you need.